# How to use Bangla in android

Tags: android

Here, I couldn't use Bangla. Is it possible to use Bangla here, like this.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CHANGE_LANGUAGE) {
Configuration c = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
String language = data.getStringExtra("language");
if(language.equals("English")) {
c.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
}else if(language.equals("German")) {
c.locale = Locale.GERMAN;
}
else if(language.equals("Bangla")) {
c.locale = Locale.Bangla;
}
```

how can I translate an app in Bangla?

Comment: I wonder why you tried `Locale.Bangla` if it's clearly not listed in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: Thanks Felix. But how can I use any language that is not listed in that documentation. any guideline or sample code plz? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html